# Issues with Radio buttons in RadioGroup in android

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

My Activity has a RadioGroup with two Radio buttons and Save button which saves a value in String variable "type". First radio button will initialize type to "Fasting" and second button will initialize "type" to "Non fasting". If I select second option, type is not getting initialized. To make second button work, I have to select first button and click Save and then if I again select second option, then it will work. Here is the code.

diabetes_options.xml

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/do_radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/do_editText1"
    android:visibility="visible" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/do_fasting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fasting" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/do_nonfasting"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Non Fasting" />
</RadioGroup>
```

DiabetesOptions.java (inside onClick method for Save Button)

```
public class DiabetesOptions extends Activity {

int typeFlag=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    rGroup=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.do_radioGroup1);
}
//This is the method invoked if we click Sabe button
public void onSave(View view) {

    rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch(checkedId){
            case R.id.do_fasting:
                type="Fasting";
                typeFlag=1;
                break;
            case R.id.do_nonfasting:
                type="Non Fasting";
                typeFlag=1;
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
    time = timeFormat.format(new Date());
    try {
        if(flag==1) {
        DiabetesDatabase entry = new DiabetesDatabase(this);
         if(typeFlag==1){
            entry.createEntry(date,time,type,level);
            Toast th = Toast.makeText(DiabetesOptions.this, "Entry Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            th.show();
         }
         else if(typeFlag==0){
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(DiabetesOptions.this);
            alertDialog.setTitle("Alert!!!");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Select FASTING or NON FASTING option");
            alertDialog.setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       dialog.dismiss();                        
                   }
               });
            alertDialog.show();
         }
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `typeFlag`?

Comment: @Szymon I edited the code above

Comment: Where is `flag` declared? I can only see it used `if(flag==1)`.

Comment: flag is declared after typeFlag.But its not the cause of the problem.
onCheckedChanged is working only after i selected first option..then hit save and come back and select second option.It is not working if i select second option in first attempt itself

Answer (score 0):

You experience this behavior, because the OnCheckedChangedListener only gets registered after you click the Save button for the first time. But at that time there will be no OnCheckedChanged event anymore you could react on, because that already happened before you clicked the button.

You also set a new OnCheckedChangedListener everytime you click on your Save button. I don't think that is what you want.

Set the OnCheckedChangeListener when you initialize your `RadioGroup` in the `onCreate` method. That should do the trick. Let me know if it works.